# jQuery attach same event to many id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

**My question is: How to attach the same series of events to many id's**

in this case I'm attaching all of this code to "#employeeBox"

```
$("#employeeBox").autocomplete({
                                source: function (request, response) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '<%:ResolveUrl("~/Lookup/SearchEnterpriseUsers")%>',
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: {
                                            featureClass: "P",
                                            style: "full",
                                            maxRows: 12,
                                            nameLike: request.term
                                        },
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                                return {
                                                    label: item.FullName,
                                                    value: item.EmployeeId
                                                }
                                            }))
                                        }
                                    })
                                },
                                minLength: 2,
                                select: function (event, ui) {
                                    alert(ui.item.value)
                                },
                                open: function () {
                                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                                },
                                close: function () {
                                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                                }
                            });
```

What if I want to attach it to many id's.

Like

```
for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
"#employee_" + i + "_Box"
```

what's the best way to do this without a lot of repeated code?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can, just add a class to all your elements and attach the event to that class instead of to a bunch of ids.

```
$('.myClass').live('myevent', function(e) { //some function });
```

Comment: Seems that OP is asking how to attach the `autocomplete` plugin to several elements. The `live()` method can't really help with this.

Comment: the concept of attaching all your elements by class to an event remains the same, though.

Comment: for this particular case you need to attach to 'load' event. unfortunately .live() cannot be used here, as the 'load' event doesn't bubble.  here is jQuery team explanation: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7702

Comment: yeah i answered this a while ago. now i'd recommend using `.delegate()`

Answer (score 3):

If you gave them all a class of employeeBox you could just do $('.employeeBox').autocomplete().